# Why does the entrypoint in Docker starts with sh in running jar?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Why does this entrypoint uses sh in running the jar? `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java -jar app.jar"]`. What would be its difference in just using `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ENTRYPOINT` directive (along with  `CMD` and `RUN`) has two forms.  If you use the [JSON-array syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) then there is no interpretation, word splitting, or any other processing; what you pass in is exactly what gets run.

```sh
# Three words
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
# You're already quoting things so spaces stay as part of each word
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "my app.jar"]
# There is no interpolation so variable names do not get expanded --
# this looks for a file literally named `$JARFILE`
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "$JARFILE"]
# There is only one command-line option with embedded spaces
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar", "-a -b -c"]
```

For a couple of cases (especially the variable expansion) you do need a shell to run.  This is where `sh -c` comes in.  It takes a *single* word and processes it as a shell command.  It then (mostly) ignores all other options, which means the `CMD` is effectively ignored.

```sh
# This expands the environment variable `$JARFILE`, but if
# you pass additional options in `CMD`, they're lost
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java -jar $JARFILE"]
```

You shouldn't actually use this syntax, though, because Docker provides a [plain-string syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) that automatically inserts `sh -c` for you.

```sh
# Exactly the same as above
ENTRYPOINT java -jar $JARFILE
# Three additional command-line options, since the shell does splitting
ENTRYPOINT java -jar app.jar -a -b -c
```

Remember that Docker will [combine the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` into a single command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  This can lead to a "container as command" pattern, but you *must* use the JSON-array form of `ENTRYPOINT`, and it *must not* have the `sh -c` wrapper.

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
CMD ["-a", "-b", "-c"]
```

(Also remember that `CMD` is much easier to override in a `docker run` command, and there is a useful pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` as a wrapper script to do first-time setup and then executing the `CMD` as the main container process.  For simple commands like what you show you might prefer `CMD`.)

Answer (score 0):

Calling Shell to execute your Java command,

1. You need to check if Shell is included in your image or the command will fail.
2. This can be a problem if you need to send any type of POSIX signals to the container since `/bin/sh` will not forward signals to the child processes.

More information about this on the following link,
https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd